# When I want to send a email from a website published on Arvixe , where is the smtp server?

Tags: c#, email, smtp

After I created a website on Arvixe, we'll call it

```
www.abcd.us
```

Accompanying the website, it also creates a email server called:

```
http://mail.abcd.us/
```

Because I need send email from this website, I created a email account named : `wp@abcd.us`

My question is : when I want to send an email from this website using c# code :

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("SERVER.arvixe.com", 465)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("wp@abcd.us", "myAccountPassword"),
    EnableSsl = true
};


MailAddress from = new MailAddress(@"wp@abcd.us", "wp");
MailAddress to = new MailAddress(@"ToAddress", "ToWho");
MailMessage myMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, to);

// set subject and encoding
myMail.Subject = "111";
myMail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

myMail.Body = "Hi test ";

myMail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

myMail.IsBodyHtml = true;                

client.Send(myMail);
```

When run at this statement:

```
client.Send(myMail);
```

The code always fail to send. I guess the smtp server may be wrong.

```
"SERVER.arvixe.com", 465
```

But I do not know what the correct server is. Where smtp server after I create a website on Arvixe?

Comment: `SERVER.arvixe.com` makes me think that it should be `abcd.arvixe.com`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I can see from [Arvixe's Knowledge Base](https://support.arvixe.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/185/20/what-are-the-settings-for-my-mail-client), there are two options. If you want to use SSL, you will need to use `mail.webeasyserve.com` port `465`. If you don't want to use SSL, then use `mail.abcd.com` port `26`.

However, this knowledge base article is two years old, so it is possible the information is out of date. Hopefully it will point you in the right direction, even if it is no longer correct.

Answer (score 0):

The domain can also be used as "localhost" and another mail port 25 (non SSL). The mail server at Arvixe can also be accessed by mail.yourdomain.com .